# Full responsive website vs mediaqueries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am always coming back to the same question when developing a website for all devices.

Does it make more sense to make everything full responsive by setting everthing in percentage values or to query a few max-width and min-width with css3 so you can have your normal website with 960px and size it down for the different devices..

For the css3 mediaqueries i would use something like this:

```
/* CSS */
/* Basic responsive */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {  
/* ..custom CSS for viewports less than 960 here */
header { /*...*/ }
section { /*...*/ }
footer { /*...*/ }
/* etc.. */
}

/* iPads (portrait) and similar tablets */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px) {
header { /*...*/ }
section { /*...*/ }
footer { /*...*/ }
/* etc.. */
}

/* Smartphones */ 
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) { 
header { /*...*/ } 
section { /*...*/ } 
footer { /*...*/ } 
/* etc.. */ 
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a bit of both. If you can write some CSS that works across all devices then that's great. For example if your header goes 100% of the width for every device there's no need to adjust it with media queries. In reality you'll find certain parts don't work and will need adjustment. This is where media queries come in.

You shouldn't treat each media query as a new stylesheet, instead it should just alter or build on the styles already defined in order to make the layout work.

Typically sites adopt a mobile-first approach. This means you start with the mobile layout and increase the complexity as the viewport width increases. The benefit of this is that older browsers will get the simplistic mobile version of the site (which at least should work, even if it isn't pretty on a desktop).

You can read more about responsive layouts here:

[Build a Responsive, Mobile-Friendly Website From Scratch](http://www.sitepoint.com/series/build-a-responsive-mobile-friendly-website-from-scratch/)

[Common Techniques in Responsive Web Design](http://www.sitepoint.com/common-techniques-in-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: +1 : clean explanation :)

Comment: Would it change something if i wanted to develop a html5 app just for tablets and smartphones? I think it's much harder to query all the display sizes than just make it in percentages..

Comment: You wouldn't need to query for every device individually. You could potentially build a responsive site that worked on everything from a 200px wide viewport to a 1500px wide viewport with maybe 3 or 4 media queries. How many media queries you need to use is determined more by the complexity of the layout than how many devices it will cater for. Don't think in terms of using percentages OR media queries, they work together. I.e a 20% column becomes too small on a mobile so you use a media query to make it 100% so it stacks under the main content, or you might hide it completely.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think i will figure out what works best while working with it. But a really good explanation there!

Comment: Since you are so competend i wanted to ask you something. I have noticed that tablets with high resolutions like the new ipad generations or even smartphones are far more over a width of 960px, nevertheless they scale the site to the 960px area without the white space. So does it make sense to develop a site optimized for 960px for desktops and high resolution tablets and one for <960px for the smaller resolution tablets and an extra mobile version for smartphones. Do tablets under 960px width also scale it to 100% eventhough they are under that resolution? Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean when an iPhone fits a 960px website into onto it's screen by 'zooming out'? By default most devices will scale the entire website to fit their screen. You can overcome this by adding the viewport meta tag (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">) to the <head> of your HTML. This stops it trying to scale the site to fit. Instead the site will act the same way it would if you reduced the width of your desktop browser window.

Comment: Oh right! I completely forgot about that. So if my website fits for most of the tablet sizes but does not for smartphone sizes (speaking about the display not the resolution) and the tablets and smartphones might have the same resolutions, how would i ensure the tablets get the normal website (which they will scale by 'zooming out') and only smartphones will get the other stylesheet (or mobilewebsite)? Is this possible? I mean how do big websites do this? They won't have the same appearance for tablets and smartphones eventhough they have the same resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you fall in such confusions, i would suggest to opt for  [**bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/)

...otherwise, `using media-queries is a better` option as it gives you wider flexibility and freedom to set values both in `pixels` as well as `percentages`.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both, or media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that if you don't use Media Queries, on every device (smartphone, desktop, laptop, etc.) you are loading all data for the website.
And if you load all data it loads also, for ex. images and that can cost a lot of Kb sent to the client browser.

With Media Queries you can set `display: none;` to images on the page and less Kb will be send to the client.

So it is important to understand that form mobile devices you should send as small portion of data as possible.

Comment: Is this correct? I always thought "display:none" would just hide the image but it will still be loaded by the mobile device browser

Comment: Right, my bad :) But anyway with display: none; page will render fatser, what is desired on mobile devices